# Why was this question closed and how is it off-topic?

Tags: discussion

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502965/have-to-take-words-from-a-text-file-and-copy-them-into-arraylist-java) was closed for being off-topic. Can somebody explain how is off-topic and who specifically says what questions are right for a forum and which ones are not?

Comment: For who says what's on-topic or not, it's listed in the [help/on-topic]. There's another page in the [help/dont-ask] about what _not_ to ask. Users with at least 3k rep can vote to close questions according to that information.

Comment: Feel free to take the [tour], which explains some of this, and read [ask], which can help with formulating good questions.

Comment: *"who specifically says what questions are right for a forum and which ones are not"* - in this case, there's a list of them right there under your question.

Comment: You have to research your question before you ask for help.  The most obvious Google query I'd think of, even though I know beans about Java, is "how to read a text file in java".  Oh, looky, top hit is an existing SO question.  We don't need another one, thanks for trying to contribute.

Comment: If you pose question as "I have problem with code" and than show code that has nothing at all with problem you described it will be closed (you ask about reading data from file, but code is just call to `Random`). Note that "read file to a list" is asked hundreds of times for all possible languages - it is very surprising your post still has less than 10 downvotes due to complete lack of research shown in the post.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that such a question has been asked and answered many, many times.  Offloading the searching onto other SO users is, well, you tell me a good term for it, so I don't get suspended:(

Comment: Forum? *Forum??* ***FORUM???***

Answer (score 5):

> Can somebody explain how is off-topic

It's already explained in the banner appearing at your question:

> > closed as off-topic by pczeus, Tom, dunni, Infer-On, Ferrybig May 28 at 21:24
> >
> > This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
> >
> > - "Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." – pczeus, dunni, Infer-On
> >       If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.

---

> and who specifically says what questions are right for a forum and which ones are not.

1st of all Stack Overflow isn't a forum.

The policies what's off-topic or not can be found in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), and close voters act based upon these policies.

It's any user participating the site that can act for moderating your question, but they need at least have gained certain privileges to flag or vote your post.

Comment: The part that I take umbrage with here is that there's no claim that the code isn't working, it's just that it's *incomplete*.  The close reason is misleading.

Answer (score 5):

There's a few things that need to be unraveled here.

First, your question was closed for the reason present in it, which for posterity's sake, reads as thus:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

However, there's a catch to this.  Your question reads as thus:

> Hi I am creating a hangman game and I have a class that is going to take words from a file each on its own line and copy them into an ArrayList one of the words will then be randomly chosen for the game. How do I copy the words so that it stores each individual line in the file as its own item in the ArrayList?
>
> -- code omitted --

In your question, there's no indication that you state that your code isn't working, but you *are* looking for a way to read lines from a text file to your application.

At ***best***, that would make your question a duplicate [of this venerable one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2788080/1079354).

Second, putting aside the nitpick that [Stack Overflow isn't a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/175248), there's a section in the Help Center on [what is okay and what isn't okay to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.